# How to include modules in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

I am learning to develop with Node.js (ie i am a newbie in this technology). I am currently following a french tutorial on Youtube to learn how to use Node.js with Express.

I am trying to include a module to be used to display JSON data, but I keep having an error message.
The code of the module is in a file named  helper.js
The code of the module is the following :

```
<code>
module.exports = function success(message,data) {
  return {
    message: message,
    data: data
  }
};
</code>
```

And I try to use the module in my code in the following way :

```
<code>

const hlp = require('./helper.js')
...

app.get('/api/pokemon/:id',(req,res)=>
{
    var pk = pks.pokemons.find(pokemon=>pokemon.id == parseInt(req.params.id))
    if (pk !== undefined) 
    {
    res.json(hlp.success(msg,pk))
    }
    else
    {
        res.send('You choose a pokemon that does not exist.')
    };
});
</code>
```

The error message says that hlp.success does not exist.
Can you help me on how to include correctly the module helper.js and use it in a correct way ?

Thank you.

Comment: The export from `helper.js` is a single function, not an object. You simply use `hlp(msg, pk)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned the function to `module.exports`.

It's name is irrelevant (unless you see it in a stack trace or want to call it recursively).

When you `hlp = require('./helper.js')` you assign the exported function to `hlp`, not to `hlp.success`.